# how do i cancel the ongoing alarm using pending intent android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

how do i cancel the ongoing alarm .please help me out to resolve this issue

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal,Boolean iscancel) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (iscancel==true)
        {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        }
        else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Looks OK. What's the problem?

Comment: the alarm is not getting turned off  when i cancel it as the alarm sound keeps on ringing....

Comment: Show the code that is making the sound. Alarms don't make sounds, they just send `Intent`s.